# Convert column in presto from epoch to date

Tags: epoch, presto, qubole

I tried this but that didn't work.

```
cast(from_unixtime('1532568232662880')) as date
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: Would it help if you remove apostrophes? Also, divide by 1000. `from_unixtime` expects a number, being number of seconds since 1970-01-01.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/44533502/65458